# Security or not in Key distribution

Tags: key-exchange, key-distribution

For example, There are 3 clients. 
I want to deliver specific value $x$ to all clients.
 $x\leftarrow {0,1,2,...,q-1}$ where q is a large prime number.
By using function 
$f(x)=x*y_{i}*z_{i}$ 
where i=1,2,3  for 3 clients
 $y_{i},z_{i}\leftarrow {0,1,2,...,q-1}$ 
 Where client 1 knows y1,z1. client 2 knows y2,z2 and client 3 knows y3,z3.
This kind of key distribution is secure or not.
If not, give me advice.

Comment: You've only specified mathematically operations. You haven't actually described what you are going to do with them. Furthermore, if you could distributed to the clients yi and zi, why couldn't you just apply a symmetric encryption to the x using yi and zi as the key?

Comment: Aron.in fact, i wanna send value x to all those clients in secret. In performance, which one is better? using symmetric encryption or just using some functions as described above.

Comment: You haven't described anything. You haven't said what you are going to send to the client. You haven't described how the client would recover the plaintext, you have literally just defined a few mathematically functions.

Comment: Aron. I am going to send  $x$ value so that clients can use that value for decryption.  The main point is delivering x value in the above style can be secure or not.

Comment: Aron. Just secure key distribution. Here, you can assume $x$ as the secret key.

Comment: You still haven't said what you are sending! You haven't described what the client receives and how he can work out what `x` is. You have missed about a dozen steps. Also, what is $*$. Because if $*$ is the multiplication operator, then that is an associative operation. How do you deal with integer overflow? STEPS WHAT ARE YOUR STEPS?

Comment: Aron.Do you know the identity-based encryption? In that, multiplication always fall into the range 0 to q-1. We don't need to worry about integer overflow. Just thinking simple case.

Comment: @astyst, what Aron is patiently trying to explain is that trying to exchange keys while ignoring logistics, e.g. transmission, storage, and implementation, is purposely ignoring most common points of failure.  Additionally "This...is secure or not" isn't a helpful question. You haven't defined the problem you are trying to solve. What is secure when used for asymmetric crypto keys may not be okay for a symmetric algo's key. There are levels of security: vs bored teenagers or vs APTs? And so on.  We cannot give you helpful answers until you complete and clarify the question.